# control an accordion set collapsed if condition in runtime C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an accordion on my aspx , I would like to control the collapsing according to a num . if num=1 then open collapseOne and close all other, if num=2 then open collapseTwo and close all other etc, How can I do that?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC, Web Forms or something else? Are you using a standard accordion library like Bootstrap or something else? Show us your relevant code so far so we can help.

Comment: I'm using asp.net web forms, I have a page that holds search control that take some search parameters and press search button that get data and display on a gridview when a row is selected the data of that row displayed in an accordion control tab according to the id of that row if id=1 then open collapseOne and close all other etc,

Comment: Bootstrap accordion would work (http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example) quite easily inside a GridView.